# When subsetting the columns on a pandas DataFrame the number of columns is being lost

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with the `pima indians` dataset.  After reading in the file via `read_csv` the `shape` looks good at `(768,9)`. But subsetting on the first 8 columns results in the `columns` dimension of the  shape getting lost:

```
pima = pd.read_csv('/git/uni/data/pima-indians-diabetes.csv', header=0)
X = pima.iloc[:,-1]
Y = pima.iloc[:,:-1]
gnb = GaussianNB()
y_pred = gnb.fit(X,Y) #  .predict(pima)
```

The surprise here is the `X.shape`: ***Why would the shape be lost?***

`pima.shape=(768, 9) **X.shape=(768,)** Y.shape=(768, 8)

So then we get bitten on the `fit`:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1 0 1 ..., 0 1 0].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

**Update** I had also tried `X = pima.iloc[:,-1].values` but it gives the same result/behavior

Comment: X=pima.iloc[:,-1].values? and Y,X is opposite  gnb.fit(Y,X.values)

Comment: You defined your X and Y backwards,  X are the features Columns :-1, while Y is your last column -1. And, standard conventions are to use X (capital) and y (lowercase).

Comment: @ScottBoston  Pls write an answer that lays it out. thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined your X and Y backwards, X are the features columns `:-1`, while Y, the target, is your last column `-1`. And, standard conventions are to use X (capital) and y (lowercase).

Therefore, your code should look like this:

```
X=pima.iloc[:,:-1]
y=pima.iloc[:,-1]
gnb = GaussianNB()
y_pred = gnb.fit(X,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

you are confusing the names , your x should be y and vice versa

```
Y= pima.iloc[:,-1]
X = pima.iloc[:,:-1]
```